# DAPR, error when reading response headers

Tags: asp.net-core, dapr

I am trying to have a very simple call to sidecar of a service:

http://localhost:50001/v1.0/invoke/blabla/method/weatherforecast

But I'm getting this error:

fail to invoke, id: blabla, err: error when reading response headers: read tcp4 127.0.0.1:64061->127.0.0.1:5001: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. Buffer size=22, contents: "Cirrato Client 21.5.0\x00""

Another point that might help is that I can see the application in Dapr's dashboard:
[image: Dapr dashboard]

this call with same configuration works on another machine, but I want to know why on some machines we get this error.

this is how I run my application and my sidecar:

dapr run --app-id blabla --app-port 5001 --dapr-http-port 50001 dotnet run

Have you ever faced this problem? Can anyone help or share idea please?

Comment: Do you happen to seen any logs associated with the called application (`blabla`)?

Comment: Yes, but nothing useful in Zipkin, it just says there was a 500 Error

Comment: My bet that this would be a bug and it is almost impossible to track the root cause without further details. You should rather report this issue at the [_dapr_ project issues tracker](https://github.com/dapr/dapr/issues/new/choose) and I might be able to help out there.

Comment: @tmarwen I've just raised the issue there, thank you.

Comment: Almost did nothing, thank you for supporting the community and the project. You may want to add a reproducible example out there to help diagnosing the issue.

Comment: You're welcome.
Actually it's nothing special, just the default template of visual studio for webAPI, the only point is about it is that when I use a sidecar for it, it cannot call the main app, while in dashboard I can see app is there.
I want to to reapeat that the same solution works well in another laptop/machine.